# If an android app is already published, can i move the key.jks file from it's original location that is in /Users?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

Will it be a problem for new keystore of another application at the same location?

Comment: quite hard to understand your question. if you submit an apk/bundle to the store, it's already a generated file, so _nothing_ you do will have an impact on your app at that point... you could technically delete every single line and nothing would change,  maybe i'm just not understanding what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can move the key to another location, but when you will rebuild a release (signed) package, you'll have to specify the new location of the key.

You can store multiple keys for different apps in the same location, as long as you name them differently.